# how to remove some punctuation from a dataframe using regex

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, punctuation

I have a python script that clean text using regex in order to get a meaningful string with removing all unnecessary characters like white space stop words, hyperlinks, punctuation.

The problem is that when i try to print the most existing word it display the below punctuation.

("''", 25), (',', 23), ('-', 22), ('’', 20),

this my code:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

def processTweet(tweet):
    '''
    parameters:
    ====================
    - tweets: list of text 
   
    functions:
    ====================
    - Remove HTML special entities (e.g. &amp;)
    - Convert @username to AT_USER
    - Remove tickers
    - convert to lowercase
    - Remove hyperlinks
    - Remove hashtags
    - Remove Punctuation and split 's, 't, 've with a space for filter
    - Remove stopwords
    - Remove words with 2 or fewer letters
    - Remove whitespace (including new line characters)
    - Remove single space remaining at the front of the tweet.
    
    '''
    # Remove HTML special entities (e.g. &amp;)
    tweet = re.sub(r'\&\w*;', '', tweet)
    #Convert @username to AT_USER
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','',tweet)
    # Remove tickers
    tweet = re.sub(r'\$\w*', '', tweet)
    # To lowercase
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    # Remove hyperlinks
    tweet = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*\/\w*', '', tweet)
    # Remove hashtags
    tweet = re.sub(r'#\w*', '', tweet)
    # Remove Punctuation and split 's, 't, 've with a space for filter
    tweet = re.sub(r'[' + punctuation.replace('@', '') + ']+', ' ', tweet)
    # Remove Punctuation and ellipses like 3 dots at the end of the line.
    tweet = tweet.replace('\u2026','')
    # Remove stopwords
    tweet = [word for word in tweet.lower().split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words("english")]
    tweet = " ".join(tweet)
    # Remove words with 2 or fewer letters
    tweet = re.sub(r'\b\w{1,2}\b', '', tweet)
    # Remove whitespace (including new line characters)
    tweet = re.sub(r'\s\s+', ' ', tweet)
    # Remove single space remaining at the front of the tweet.
    tweet = tweet.lstrip(' ') 
    return tweet
```

Comment: @ggorlen what you mean?

Comment: string.punctuation includes: ','     '-'     "''"    
so why it did not been removed ??

Comment: Well, that wasn't it--apparently it's able to treat `[]` literally within a character class. I figured it'd break the regex. This seems to work for me... I ran `>>> processTweet(".foo. bar. bar, a-f ")` and got `'foo bar bar '` as expected. Can you show the input tweet that is breaking it please?

Comment: `[ and ] have special meaning in regex along with a lot of other characters in the string. You need to escape them with a backslash`


so how to do it ?? you mean to add a backslash before  **',' '-' "''"** characters?

Comment: let say this example : `""@Amani_ @LSal92 @Haidar33 many thanks for all ur kind words..love u all. - ,  ; '' _ …`

it will keep the first **'** and the last **'**

Comment: That also worked fine for me. I got `'many thanks for all kind words love all'`. The quotes are part of the printed output on the repl. Probably `for` would be removed but I don't have `ntlk` installed but that certainly wouldn't add anything.

Comment: mmm so  how come it is showing in my result as the most existing words ??

this is odd ... i will debug each row and see

Comment: I recommend posting a [mcve] with failing input/output so I can simply copy and run the code to see the problem.

Comment: so in my case i must post the hall corpus of the dataframe.

Comment: That doesn't sound minimal. You probably want to binary search your input to locate a single failing tweet or set of failing tweets. And, as you mentioned, I doubt all of these operations are responsible for the problem. You can probably remove most of them to find the one that's misbehaving.

Comment: yes that is why i need do my own debug because i do not know which rows makes the error